# loading html files on different AVDs?

Tags: android, html, webview

I was just wondering why internaly stored html files behave differently on different APIs. like Galaxy Nexus AVD it wraps the html page whereas on Nexus S only the text shows on 2/3rd of the screen.

```
  myWebView.setInitialScale(1); 
  myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
  myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
  myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
  myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/FE/index.html");
```

is there anything i can add/remove to make it API indipendent and make it fit on all AVDs.

Comment: You should use "%" with the hight & width etc . So that everything will be in same format in all APIs .
<input type = "button" height ="10%" width = "20%" />

Answer (score 0):

please add

```
   myWebView.getSettings().setJavascriptenabled(true);
   myWebView.getSettings().setpluginstate(PLUGINS.ON);
```